# How to open an image from an url with opencv using requests from python

Tags: python, opencv, python-requests

I am trying to open a large list of images using OpenCV on python, because I need to work with them latter.

Actually, I can achieve this goal with pillow like this:

```
url = r'https://i.imgur.com/DrjBucJ.png'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
guess = Image.open(response).resize(size)
```

I am using the library `requests` from python.

The `response` looks like this: `b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\xdb\...`

And if I am not wrong, those are the values of the pixels from the image of the url, correct?

My question is: how can I do the same with OpenCV?

I have tried it like:

```
resp = requests.get(url)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

And I get this error:

```
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I got the code from this web: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/02/convert-url-to-image-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: `urllib` differs from `requests`, try `resp.raw`.

Comment: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !buf.empty() && buf.isContinuous() in function 'cv::imdecode_'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just forgot `stream=True` and `.raw` in `requests.get`

> resp = requests.get(url, `stream=True`)`.raw`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests

url = r'https://i.imgur.com/DrjBucJ.png'
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# for testing
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

To answer your question

`.raw` mean that you want to retrieve the response as a ***stream of bytes*** and ***the response will not evaluated or transformed by any measure*** (so it will not decode gzip and deflate transfer-encodings) but with `.content` ***The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you***.

In your case it will be better to use `.content` over `.raw`

**the following note from Requests package documentation**

> **Note**
>   An important note about using Response.iter_content versus Response.raw. Response.iter_content will automatically decode the gzip and deflate transfer-encodings. Response.raw is a raw stream of bytes – it does not transform the response content. If you really need access to the bytes as they were returned, use Response.raw.

**References:**

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain me what is the difference between content and raw, and what does the stream=True do?

Answer (score 0):

@[Mohamed Saeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5225572/mohamed-saeed)'s answer solved your problem. Below is an alternative solution to fetch image from a url:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen

req = urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/DrjBucJ.png')
image = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(image, -1) 

cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```