# Discord.Py blend pictures and send them without dowload them

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, opencv, bytesio

I have the following problem:

1.- I want to send a file in discord without dowloading. I don't know if this is posible but I want to send it for example with BytesIo.

2.- I have one picture saved on my Bot files and the other one comes from ctx.author.avatar

3.- I want to blend both images and send the result. With blend I mean like for example if I would be using cv2 I would use addWeighted().

The Code I have right know what does is dowload the picture of the member, using cv2 to read both pictures, resize them and use addWeighted. After that I save the blend picture and I send it as a message. When all It's done I delete the pictures (both, the avatar and the blend one). From my point of view this is really inefficient, thats why I want know if there is a way using PIL and BytesIo or something to use the dataArray to blend them and send it without dowload it.

**So in short**, I want to know if there is a way to blends both images without download the second one (member avatar picture) and send it without dowloading the blend image.

I can the code I already have if needed but as my code is download the picture I guess that won't help.

Comment: You can't use the avatar image without downloading it; that is, in order to get the image data, you must receive the image data from the Discord server. I assume you mean that you don't want to save the image to the disk?

Comment: Exactly, I dont want to save the image to the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found at the end to solve it, was using just Pillow doing the following:

```
image1 = Image.open("img.jpg", mode='r')
image2 = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
```

With I have both images on memory, so I just needed to resize both of them and blend. Finally I just used io.Bytes() to make into bytes and send it.
How to blend -> https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/blend

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image's URL from the message ([Get a picture from the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206958/get-a-picture-from-the-message)):

```
message.attachments[0].url
```

Then load the image into memory with the `requests` library ([How to open an image from an url with opencv using requests from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539233/how-to-open-an-image-from-an-url-with-opencv-using-requests-from-python))

Comment: Well Im using url = ctx.author.avatar_url and It works properly, the onliest problem is that when I do cv2.addWeighted and I save into a variable I dont know how to send it because I always get this error Command raised an exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 1400: 
invalid start byte