# cv2.VideoCapture( ' html live stream'? )

Tags: python, html, opencv, http, raspberry-pi

Gets error when trying to open livestream.
I'm streaming this from my raspberry pi to my view it on windows so I can run opencv and yolo.
Is there a way to do this with opencv?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://______/html/#')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(50)
    if key == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's at the end of that url? A website? A jpeg image? Mp4 video? Flash video? Prime video Website stream?

Comment: Raspberrypi Cam control. It shows a little window of the pi camera and settings under it. I did manage to screen record the browser using this code but I wish I could just view the url and have opencv view the pixel range of where the live stream is showing on the page. https://holypython.com/how-to-use-imagegrab-of-cv2/

Comment: VideoCapture doesn't work from arbitrary web pages. you need to find out how that "pi cam control" thing streams video, meaning *the URL* that actually sends just the video and no html or anything. these questions show up regularly. I'm sure you can find this exact question and solutions to it already on this site.

Answer (score 0):

So the URL I was trying to connect to had a little display of the livestream from the raspberry pi and the settings under it. What I had to do along with the code from this answer was right click on the live stream display, open it up in another tab and use the URL from that tab. It's about 2-3 seconds off though.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539561/17280268

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://345.63.46.1256/html/cam_pic_new.php?time=1642941457007&p')

#^^ Opened in new tab URL ^^
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://345.63.46.1256/html/')

cv2.namedWindow('live cam', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #img_resize = cv2.resize(frame, (960, 540))
    cv2.imshow('live cam', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```